# Is it possible to virtualize the API LAYER and don't write code?

Tags: .net-core, e2e-testing, api-design, code-reuse, documentation-generation

I was surfing on internet for solutions and tools related to the API Layer and I find a company (maybe a startup) that is developing an ecosystem that allow to "virtualize the API Layer" (at the moment only in .net Core). It seems they allow to don't code the Api layer, don't write documentation of endpoints, don't writeE2E test (automatically inferred), change behaviour of endpoints at runtime and reuse the entire stack in another project. Do you think is it really possible something like this and useful in the world of API development? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, your wondering about setting up an API layer with just the endpoints, but the endpoints have empty logic in them, right?

If so, then yes its possible to do this with a variety of tools. One tool I use is Postman, which allows you to setup a "skeleton" API you can call for design/testing purposes.

It allows standing up a mock server that hosts your skeleton API, in which any consumer can hook into.

Comment: It seems different from Postman; if I understand well, you have to write just the business logic, than this KOREBI, sit on top of the business logic and is able to inferred automatically documentations, e2e test (without write a single row of code). It looks like this Korebi can "read" your business logic and provide you all what you need.